# When is Control.Visible = true turns out to be false?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WinForms project that's very wizard like in its functionality. The individual steps live on a class called StepPanel, which inherits from the Panel control, within the form and those panels are organized in an array.

What I've run into is that when UpdateUI() is called and walks the array, adjusts the wizards step title text for the current step, it makes sure that all of the inactive steps are hidden, and ensures that the active step is visible, in the right spot, and is the right size.

Here's the code:

```
    private void UpdateUI()
    {
        // If the StepIndex equals the array length, that's our cue 
        // to exit.
        if (StepIndex == Steps.Length)
        {
            Application.Exit();
            return;
        }

        for (var xx = 0; xx < Steps.Length; xx++)
        {
            if (xx == StepIndex)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Steps[xx].Title))
                {
                    LabelStepTitle.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
                    LabelStepTitle.Text = Steps[xx].Title;
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelStepTitle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    LabelStepTitle.Text =
                        Resources.UiWarning_StepTitleNotSet;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Steps[xx].Visible = false;
            }
        }

        Steps[StepIndex].Top = 50;
        Steps[StepIndex].Left = 168;
        Steps[StepIndex].Width = 414;
        Steps[StepIndex].Height = 281;
        Steps[StepIndex].Visible = true;

        SetNavigationButtonState(true);
    }
```

When everything is said and done, Steps[StepIndex].Visible == false.

I'm still perplexed by this behavior because I was working less than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: have you changed anything in the last 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes, it's in active development at the moment.

Comment: What does the method `SetNavigationButtonState` do?

Comment: Across the bottom of the form are three buttons: Back/Restart, Next/Finish, and Cancel. This method consolidates the logic for maintaining their state (i.e. enabled/disabled, current button text) based on which step in the process you're in.

Comment: maybe whatever you changed recently broke this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you set a parent/container control to `Visible = false` then setting any child controls to `Visible = true` will have no effect what so ever. The `Visible` property of the child control will still be `false`.

I don't know if it's what happens in this case since I don't know the structure of the controls but it seems to be a likely scenario.

To solve this you need to first set the parent/contianer control to `Visible = true` and THEN the child control(s).

Comment: It appears that the StepPanel became the child of another StepPanel that was hidden.

Comment: Good that you solved it. My last remark is actually not true. You can set the child controls visible property to true before the parent. The property will remain false but when you set the parent property to true .Net will "magically" remember the state of the child controls and set them accordingly.

Comment: I think it all happened because I was trying to line up StepPanels, one on top of another, and the designer was trying to be helpful. I've added code that if the StepPanel's parent isn't the form to remove it and then add it to the form's control collection.

Answer (score 0):

`if (xx == StepIndex)`

Is only going to be true and the end of the loop unless I am missing something.

Comment: Since we don't know where StepIndex is set you cannot make that assumption.

Comment: StepIndex tracks what step the user is on and this correlates to the StepPanel in the array.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen you are correct I misread the code at the top.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. When you attach a debugger on the line:

```
SetNavigationButtonState(true);
```

does `Steps[StepIndex].Visible == true`? If so, then make sure that `StepIndex` is actually the index you expected (not off by 1, and not reflecting the "previous" step). If you verify that the correct step is set to true, then you must be updating it somewhere else.

if `Steps[StepIndex].Visible == false` right after you set it to true, then either the getter on the Visible property is returning based on some calculation or an event was triggered that is changing it back to false.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue using MDIForm in VB.net and Sani Singh Huttunen explanation is correct for me.

I post this answer to give more explanations and also a specific solution or a work around.

When I click on a specific menu to load a new MDI Child form, my program excute following code

```
Dim frm As New FrmPaiement
frm.MdiParent = Me
Call frm.NewRecord()
Call ReorganizeControlTopPositions(frm.DataPanel)
frm.Show()
```

where `FrmPaiement` is a Form class that originally contains a lot of controls and `DataPanel` is central panel that contains all data TextBox, CheckBox, ComboBox and DateBox controls.

[image]

But these time, some controls are hidden in `frm.NewRecord()` function.

[image]

`ReorganizeControlTopPosition()` function is called to reduce gaps between remainding visible controls

[image]

For information, VB.Net code of `ReorganizeControlTopPositions()` is following

```
Public Sub ReorganizeControlTopPositions(ctlContainer As Panel)
    'Put all controls in a List(Of Control) and sort it on Top position
    For Each ctl As Control In ctlContainer.Controls
        lstControls.Add(ctl)
    Next

    lstControls.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Top.CompareTo(y.Top))

    'Reduce gaps between 2 visibles controls

    Dim iLastTop As Integer = -1
    Dim nInvisible = 0
    Dim iLastControlTop As Integer = 0

    For Each ctl In lstControls
        If nInvisible > 0 Then
            If ctl.Visible Then
                If ctl.Top = iLastControlTop Then
                    ctl.Top = iLastTop
                Else
                    iLastControlTop = ctl.Top
                    ctl.Top = iLastTop + 32
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If ctl.Visible Then
            iLastTop = ctl.Top
        Else
            nInvisible += 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**EXPLANATION OF ERROR**

Since `ReorganizeControlTopPositions()` function is called before `frm.Show()` function, MDI Child is hidden and in debug mode, `ctl.Visible` contains always `False` !

If initialisation code if changed so that `ReorganizeControlTopPositions()` is called after `frm.Show()` call, program runs correctly and `ctl.Visible` contains "correct" value.

```
Dim frm As New FrmPaiement
frm.MdiParent = Me
Call frm.NewRecord()
frm.Show()
Call ReorganizeControlTopPositions(frm.DataPanel)
```

The only problem is that MDI Form is shortly (very quicly) displaying controls with gaps and a micro secund later without gaps.

The problem is linked to Microsoft implementation of Visible property.

Setting `Visible` property seems to change visible value of control but getting `Visible` value return only `True` if `Visible` property of control is `True` and also all containers containing this control are visibles !

What is written on Control.Visible property on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visible?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is extremly confuse !!!

Return `True` if the control and all its child controls are displayed; otherwise, false. The default is true.

The correct definition sould be

Return `True` if the control and all its PARENT controls are displayed; otherwise, false. The default is true.